# MongoDB compound indexing long text on exact match

Tags: mongodb

I have a model that looks something like this:

```
{
  _id: '...',
  voice: '<dialect code>', // examples: 'en-US', 'en-GB', 'es', 'de', ...
  text: '<plaintext up to 200 characters>',
  ... // other non-unique values
}
```

The combination of `voice` & `text` should be a unique value.
I am currently doing lookups on these two values on exact matches, not doing text search. In Mongoose, an example lookup is like this:

```
SoundRequest.findOne({ voice: 'en-US', text: 'Hello, world' });
```

This lookup is taking several seconds at the moment, while under heavy load & with no index, and I am very interested in improving the performance here.

How can I best add an index on this collection? I tried to do a compound index, but I am getting an error `WiredTigerIndex::insert: key too large to index`. I assume this is because some of the entries are currently using the maximum 200 characters and this is larger than MongoDB's Index Key Length Limit.

What is the best option for me? I am aware of the following possibilities:

1. Set `failIndexKeyTooLong: false`
2. Use a hashed index only on `text`
3. Do a Full Text Index, despite only needing to lookup exact matches
4. Only add an Index on `voice` (would this even improve performance?)
5. Do my own hashing? (Ouch)

What would give me the best performance? Will any of these options even improve performance?

I am currently sitting at about 1.5 million records and db performance has significantly gotten worse over time and the size will probably grow by about 1 million records every month.

Comment: The entire topic of indexing is highly depending on your specific environment and data flow, e.g. if your collection is heavily written to or just being read etc. Then, what's also very important is your data distribution (read up on the "cardinality" of an index). And there's more. To me, a hashed index on the `text`field sounds about right and probably sufficient if you always ask for `text` in your queries. `Voice` won't be overly selective so won't contribute an awful lot. Try it out and measure!!!

Comment: @dnickless This was the perfect answer, honestly. Thank you. The first thing I tried after reading your comment was a hashed index on `text`. On my local machine, with 1.5M records, the lookup time went from 600ms to 0ms. Can't get much faster than that =)

Comment: Sounds like it could be hard to beat indeed. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @dnickless, I did some of my own investigation.

The first thing I tried was doing a hashed index on the `text` field.
On my local machine, with 1.5M records, the average lookup was about 600ms before adding the index, and **0ms** afterwards.

This was a good enough answer for me and the one I have now implemented on my production server with no issues. I also saw the same performance improvement in production.

Perhaps there is still a better answer, but this is good enough for now.